# Piece of equipment similar to syringe for gas collection

Tags: equipment

I'm looking for the name of a piece of equipment similar to a syringe. The only difference is that this item is made entirely from glass. The purpose of this equipment is to collect gases.

Here is a photo of two of these pieces of equipment connected to a gas-washing bottle:

[image: Two of those things connected threw am gas-washing bottle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of laboratory glassware is a [gas syringe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_syringe). Apparently, gas syringes are not standardized; however, typical models have a capacity of 100 ml. Some models include a GL 14 screwthread tube, a stopcock, or a three-way stopcock.